# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adapter is detached

Tags: android, adapter, apache-httpclient-4.x, illegalstateexception, android-volley

When I log in my application i give this kind of error in Logcat :

```
0191-10213/com.telera.ui.activities E/ODE-AL﹕ [1413] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adapter is detached.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adapter is detached.
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.assertAttached(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:90)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(HttpClientStack.java:83)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
```

What can i do for fixing this problem ?

Comment: Show us some code of where you use/create the NetworkDispatcher.

Comment: op is using volley line 105 `NetworkDispacther` is   `NetworkResponse networkResponse = mNetwork.performRequest(request);`

Comment: @Raghunandan i don't understand. I can not edit NetworkDispatcher

Comment: @JohnError don't worry just ignore the comment

Comment: @Raghunandan is this a deadly error for me?

Comment: @Raguhnandan, that's just the stack trace telling you where it is going wrong. It does not, however, give us context about how the NetworkDispatcher is being used.

Comment: @ThaMe90 its a library project referenced in Android project. Without code its hard to spot a mistake. I just wanted to tell that op himself has no defined that class

Answer (score 1):

Are you using cookies and a custom stack?

When using cookies you can not have multiple requests at once and should set `DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 1` in the `RequestQueue` class.

Comment: How can I set DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE to 1 if i add volley library from build.gradle file?

Comment: Dig into the code and see if there is a set method to override that value - or simply import the volley project code - easy to do.